# Come posso dire "forget about it" in italiano?

Tags: meaning, translation

Come posso dire "forget about it" quando voglio dire a una persona di non pensare più ad una situazione perché ho già risolto?

Comment: Puoi dire semplicemente **scordatelo**, **dimenticatelo**, **lascia perdere** oppure semplicemente **non persarci piú**

Comment: Grazie! Questa è la risposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Letteralmente la traduzione è **dimenticalo**.

Puoi dire in alternativa **scordatelo**, **dimenticatelo**, **lascia perdere** oppure semplicemente **non pensarci più**.

Comment: Anche "lascia stare" oppure "non fa niente"

Comment: Scusa, una pignoleria estrema: “dimenticalo” sarebbe più la traduzione “letterale” di *forget it*. Una resa letteralissima (qualunque cosa ciò significhi) di *forget about it* dovrebbe essere qualcosa come “dimentica su ciò”, che ovviamente è illeggibile; un po' meno peggio è “dimenticatene”. Ma, come spieghi giustamente, in un qualsiasi vero testo o discorso il senso è “lascia perdere” e analoghi.

Comment: C'è un refuso: "pensarci", non "persarci"

Comment: Corretto. Grazie @Benedetta